# Exporting metrics from Prometheus to Elastics Search for better monitoring capabilities

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, kibana, prometheus, monitoring

I want to use Prometheus to monitor Spark (using spark driver API) but I also want to use Kibana for better investigation capabilities.
So I want to export those metrics from Prometheus also to Elastic Search as records to show on Kibana.

Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this [blog](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/prometheus-monitoring) where they have shown various way to export prometheus metrics to Elasticsearch.

You can use [metricbeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/metricbeat/current/metricbeat-module-prometheus.html) as well to get data from prometheus as it provide module for same.

Also, if you are using latest version of Elasticsearch then you can explore Elastic Agent and Fleet as well, which have [integration for prometheus](https://docs.elastic.co/en/integrations/prometheus).

Comment: Do you know what are the main differences between those 2 options?

Comment: @idanahal both are same only because elastic agent run metricbeat only internally. With ElasticAgent you will get unified UI from where you can manage configuration easily.